# What's the difference between shape(150,) and shape (150,1)?

Tags: python, numpy

What's the difference between shape(150,) and shape (150,1)?

I think they are the same, I mean they both represent a column vector.

Comment: they are different. they are stored differently. they both may "represent" the same information, but they cant be interchanged freely, because of the actual structural difference. The first is a 1 dimensional storage. (for example, array of values). The second is 2 dimensional. (Array of array (having length 1) of values)

Comment: It's the difference between `[1, 2, 3]` and `[[1],[2],[3]]`. Kind of same (in that both contain three scalars), yet not.

Comment: They are isomorphic.

Comment: @Amadan I think it's more like [[1,2,3]].

Comment: the trailing comma is actually not mandatory too

Comment: @FarhoodET: That would be shape `(1, 3)`, not `(3, 1)`.

Comment: @Nenri: The comma is most definitely mandatory. `(150,)` is a 1-tuple. `(150)` is a number in parentheses.

Comment: @Amadan ya but putting a number as a shape works too

Comment: `x = np.reshape([1, 2, 3], 3)
print(x.shape)` this will give u `(3,)` that's what i meant

Comment: @Nenri: The shape is still `(3,)`. The fact that numpy automatically tuplifies a scalar for you if you pass one as a shape into a function that takes a shape parameter is not really pertinent. Besides, saying "comma is not mandatory" suggests you preferred `(3)` - which is a useless use of parentheses, and very likely to lead to a tuple-vs-scalar error down the road.

Comment: But i meant using an actual scalar instead of a tuple, so i guess i should have said "using a tuple isn't mandatory too". And even if it's not pertinent, numpy works like that. I personally just don't like the `(x,)` notation, that i find not pythonic. But anyway, this is leading nowhere, and out of subject

Comment: The `(x,)` notation IS pythonic; it's python's way of displaying a single element `tuple`. It isn't a numpy innovation.

Answer (score 3):

Both have the same values, but one is a vector and the other one is a matrix of the vector. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
```

And the output is:

```
(5,)
(5, 1)
```

Comment: Same concept but the vector is transposed.

Answer (score 0):

Although they both occupy *same space* and *positions in memory*,

> I think they are the same, I mean they both represent a column vector.

No they are not and certainly not according to NumPy (ndarrays).

The main difference is that the

shape `(150,)` => is a 1D array,  whereas
shape `(150,1)` => is a 2D array

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this see to come from two misconceptions.

- not realizing that `(5,)` is a 1 element tuple.
- expecting MATLAB like matrices

---

Make an array with the handy `arange` function:

```
In [424]: x = np.arange(5)                                                      
In [425]: x.shape                                                               
Out[425]: (5,)             # 1 element tuple
In [426]: x.ndim                                                                
Out[426]: 1
```

`numpy` does not automatically make matrices, 2d arrays.  It does not follow MATLAB in that regard.

We can reshape that array, adding a 2nd dimension.  The result is a `view` (sooner or later you need to learn what that means):

```
In [427]: y = x.reshape(5,1)                                                    
In [428]: y.shape                                                               
Out[428]: (5, 1)
In [429]: y.ndim                                                                
Out[429]: 2
```

The display of these 2 arrays is very different.  Same numbers, but the layout and number of brackets is very different, reflecting the respective shapes:

```
In [430]: x                                                                     
Out[430]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [431]: y                                                                     
Out[431]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

The shape difference may seem academic - until you try to do math with the arrays:

```
In [432]: x+x                                                                   
Out[432]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])     # element wise sum
In [433]: x+y                                                                   
Out[433]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

How did that end up producing a (5,5) array?  Broadcasting a (5,) array with a (5,1) array!